# Interpolation with conditionals

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

I want to insert data into a string via interpolation. I want to check if `@call.transferred_from` is `nil`, and if so, output `@call.transfer_from_other`; else output `@call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name)` along with `@call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address)`.

Here is my code example:

```
"#{if @call.transferred_from.nil? @call.transfer_from_other else @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address) end}"
```

Doing this gives me the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
```

I'm not sure where to go. Any help would be appreciated.

Update: 08/04/14

I moved the conditional into a private controller method as follows:

```
 def transfer_from_address
    if @call.transferred_from.nil?
      @call.transfer_from_other
    else
      @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) + ' ' + @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address)
    end
  end
```

Then I call the following using string interpolation.

```
#{transfer_from_address}
```

This seems to work, but I'm not sure that it's proper Ruby.

Comment: What do you mean by "along with"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not really answering your question, but I'd caution about putting this much logic in an interpolation. While its totally doable, it makes your code very hard to understand.

The fundamental issue I see with your particular issue is you're trying to return 2 things somehow, yet you're just putting both of them next to eachother which is not valid ruby.

Assuming this is in an interpolation you'd want to somehow return them together ..

```
#{
  @call.transferred_from.nil? ?
  @call.transfer_from_other :
  @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) + ' ' + @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address)
}
```

I'd really suggest you move this into a variable or a method tho .. and just reference it in the interpolation.

This could look something like:

```
facility_name_and_address = @call.transferred_from.nil? ? @call.transfer_from_other : @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) + ' ' + @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address)
{
  :body => facility_name_and_address
}
```

Comment: I was actually just writing this same solution and it worked.  Thanks.  I understand that it's hard to read and is not valid Ruby.  What would be the better (and proper) way to handle this?  I'd like to follow the constraints of Ruby and do this right.

Comment: I don't really see the full context of what you're writing .. but updated the above to reflect what I mean

Comment: It made sense to me, and moving it into a method works fine.  Please see my update to my original question.  I assume it's still not valid Ruby trying to attach two objects together?  But so far, it's working.

Comment: You don't even need to interpolate it anymore if that's the only thing you need in the string. `foo == "#{foo}"` if foo is a String

Comment: Well there's other objects I need to interpolate in the string.  My original question was solely doing conditionals on one interpolation instance.  I really appreciate all your help.  I'm up and running :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I would suggest adding a method to `@call` which does the job:

```
class Call
  def transfer_text
    return transfer_from_other if transferred_from.nil?
    "#{transferred_from.try(:facility_name)} #{transferred_from.try(:facility_address)}"
  end
end
```

Then simply calling `@call.transfer_text` should provide the needed text.

---

If you want to be more sophisticated, and you don't want trailing white-space in case `facility_name` or `facility_address` are `nil`, you can create a list of them, and join them with white space:

```
[transferred_from.try(:facility_name), transferred_from.try(:facility_address)].compact.join(' ')
```

This will make sure spaces will be only between to non-nil elements. If both are `nil`, and empty string will be the result (rather than a space), and if one is `nil`, it won't have a leading/trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put either a semicolon or `then` right after the condition.

```
if @call.transferred_from.nil?; @call.transfer_from_other ...
```

But in your case, there is not much point in putting the entire condition inside a string interpolation. It is better to do the condition outside the string.

By the way, if you fix your first error, then you might encounter the next error:

```
@call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address)
```

To fix that as well, I think you should do

```
@call.transferred_from.instance_eval{|e| e.nil? ?
  @call.transfer_from_other.to_s :
  "#{e.try(:facility_name)} #{e.try(:facility_address)}"
}
```

Comment: I did this `#{if @call.transferred_from.nil? ; @call.transfer_from_other end}` and it did output the @call.transfer_from_other properly.  But how do I handle the "else" @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address)?

Comment: I'm trying to say if @call.transferred_from.nil? then output @call.transfer_from_other otherwise output @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) along with @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address)  Basically if there's no facility set output the other, otherwise output the facility name and address.  Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: What do you mean by "along with"? That is not clear.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear.  I am wanting to say else @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address) so basically output that if all else fails. Your answer takes care of checking if @call.transferred_from.nil? and outputting @call.transfer_from_other.  But I need to output the facility_name and facility_address if all else fails.

Comment: You cannot output that because that is not a valid Ruby object. Aligning two objects side by side is invalid in Ruby (except for a very special case like string literal concatenation, which is irrelevant here).

Comment: So @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) and @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address) are not Ruby objects?  I can call them from my view and from the console properly.

Comment: No. Each of them are Ruby objects, but what you get by aligning them side by side is not a Ruby object.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're trying to say now.  So how would I align the two objects?  Or would this best be handled with a conditional outside of the string and if so, how would I do this?

Comment: I think I got what you wanted to do.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty simple what I want to do, but as you mentioned and @piotrb mentioned it's not valid Ruby.  Should I somehow move this out into a different method in my controller?  That would probably make a lot more sense then trying to do conditionals inside string interpolation.

Comment: Probabaly that is the way you should go.

Comment: I moved the conditional to a private controller method then called the method in the string interpolation and it works great.  Thanks for all your help.  You and @piotrb were very helpful.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

why not using

```
:body => "#{@call.transferred_from.nil? ? @call.transfer_from_other :    @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address)"
```

but anyway I would not use this compact syntax for better maintainability

Comment: I tried this: `#{@call.transferred_from.nil? ? @call.transfer_from_other : @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_name) @call.transferred_from.try(:facility_address)}` But it throws an exception:syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting '}'